# ASP.NET MVC return Full Image From URL - Keep Same Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC Controller/Action and I want to return an Image hosted elsewhere.

Something like:

```
    public ActionResult GetImage()
    {
        var img = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";

        //return File(img, "image/jpg"); 
    }
```

**I want to keep the same route though `Controller/GetImage`**

Is this even possible without downloading the image inside my Action and returning the bytes?

Comment: Only if you are just passing the path to the called (browser) and have it call the external URL Otherwise you have to initiate the external request and forward the stream to the client.

Comment: Change ActionResult to String and return the img var

Comment: @Nick that simply returns the URL text as a string. It doesn't return the image binary.